# Show blank space in crystal report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have four sections, Report header,page header,detail and footer. All my data are listed in footer section. 
The problem is that when I print the data, the 3 sections above show big blank space.

[image]

How can I remove that blanks space??

Thanks in advance!! :)

Comment: you need to supress the section... right clcik on the section and click `Supress` and you will get rid of the space

Comment: not working, any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your report is that you have data in wrong section. Since you have 4 sections

1. Report header
2. Page header
3. Detail
4. Footer

You are missing Report footer or Page footer (in your description of question or in your report). In your case, your data is probably in Page footer which is always printed at the bottom of the page (you can't change that). To avoid that you need to put your data in Report header, Page header or Report footer with unchecked option "print at bottom of page" (check on picture) and suppress all other sections.

Hope it helps

[image]